# Seeking parallel line function for slds

Tags: geoserver, sld

I am attempting to make an sld style which symbolizes a line with an offset. I have tried with filters, functions online graphics but can achieve only ugly results. The line consists out of 2 line symbolizers. one thick underlying line which is displayed at an offset westerly of the achse. The other thinner line lies above the thicker line overlapping the easterly edge of the thicker line.

an example is here: http://maps.zgb.de/rrop/sld_img/style_hatchedline_offset.png

How do I produce this sld?

Answer (score 5):

No - it's pretty hard to do.
See http://lin-ear-th-inking.blogspot.co.uk/2010/11/single-sided-buffers-in-jts.html for a discussion of why.