# Both dashed line and stroke line in parallel in the SLD

Tags: qgis, geoserver, sld

I just started in GIS. How can I draw in the GeoServer's SLD editor, both dashed and stroke line in parallel?
like below:

```
-----------------------------------
___________________________________
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Not Possible .. have a look at [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29375/is-there-a-parellel-line-function-for-slds) previous Question which has a [link](http://lin-ear-th-inking.blogspot.co.uk/2010/11/single-sided-buffers-in-jts.html) explaining why ..

Your only option is to create the geometries twice with an offset and style them separately ..